# RedShift Update:ERROR: XX000: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am going to start working on RedhShift, so I have started making easy querys.
But there is an easy query that it is not working.
this is the error that appear, and i do not understand why. ERROR: XX000: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate

```
  UPDATE table1  SET    org='99'   from (SELECT  '100000' AS org   FROM     table2) yyy
```

I know that the query is simple, but i do a lot of updates from selects with joins and i want to know the correct way to make the update work.

thank you

Comment: Lovely. What's the problem then?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: so you're looking at a 2 year data range to get the cumulative sum for a the LAST 12 months?  So today being `20170725` 1 year ago would be `20160725` and the cumulative sum for 2016 July would be from 2015 August to 2016 July right?  So conditional aggregation on sales looking back only 12 months and then a where clause to limit to 2 years? and a group by to parse the date to a monthyear?  Without sample data and expected results difficult to envision.

Comment: yes, that is what i need. the data is like this:

Comment: It would help if you would also post an illustration of the kind of result you want.

Comment: i show the output i need. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an information about only sales during the last year, appropriate condition in the `WHERE` clause should be present.
For Oracle you can use the following query:

```
SELECT date,
  product,
  sum(sales) over (partition by product order by date) as cumulative 
FROM sales
WHERE date >= add_months(sysdate, -12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no missing month and you want total sales for each product, you could use the following query -

```
SELECT "Date"
    , "Product"
    , "Sales"
    , SUM("Sales") OVER (PARTITION BY "Product" ORDER BY "Date" ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Cumulative
FROM Sales;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aea65/44)